# find_element_by_xpath doesn't fit and I don't know how to find it

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, find

I'm **scraping** a page that Is basically a search engine. The fact Is that I could only find the element by xpath In that code, for example:

*I want to specify the h2*

```
<div class="header">
<i id="print" data-nb="1609606440">
</i>
<h2>JOAO SAMPAIO DOS SANTOS</h2>
<ul> <li class="numeric">CPF: 35954825300</li>
<li class="numeric">Nasc.: 22/06/1950 (69 Anos)</li> </ul>
</div>
```

The problem Is that the page can chage It structure depending on the results, so the xpath might not work In some cases. How could I do this?

EDIT:
The first image we will consider "normal", and I wanna get the highlighted text. The second one shows a notification (highlighted) witch changes the xpath. I wanna get the same thing on the two cases

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you share the url?

Comment: Unfortunately It's private from a company that I'm partner and requires user and pass :(

Comment: then it's going to be tough to help without seeing the html structure, or possibly the `get`, `post` requests. Are there any attributes within the elements that are consistent? What do you mean by wanting to specify the h2? Can you give an example of how 2 different search results will look (that are different xpaths)?

Comment: Thanks for your help man! I'v added some screenshots that will of course will help you to understand better

Comment: so in both cases you want what? Whats your expected output for each of these? The content under `h2` tag?

Comment: In both cases I want the name of the client (witch is hilighted on the first screenshot)...

In the second case the difference is that a notification appears, then the xpath changes, but the client name is still there.

Comment: My problem is that the page code just let me do the `find_element` usind the xpath, because It does note have an ID for example... And the xpath changes on second case

Comment: Right, but why not just get the `h2` tag then. You don't necessarily need to use xpath. Shoot me an email and we can discuss "offline". jason.schvach@gmail.com Send me the part of the code where you're trying to find the element by xpath

Comment: I can't just get the `h2` tag because the page has others `h2` tags... Is it possible to specify the div of the tag I'm trying to get? Thanks for your help man, aprecciate that

Comment: Yes, ya, that's precisely what I'm getting at. Getting the specifc parent tag is an option too. It's just a matter of finding the unique element. Or if the `h2` element is always in the same spot (like if it's always the first `h2` in the html. But

Answer (score 0):

Working XPath for both cases :

```
//h2[preceding::*[1][name()="i" and contains(@id,"print")][@data-nb]]
```

We look for an h2 element following an i element containing specific attributes.